# Law of energy conservation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Can there be any such point or situation on the earth where the potential energy and kinetic energy of the body both are maximum or both are minimum simultaneously .

Comment: In a simple harmonic oscillator, when the mass reaches it's maximum distance and is no longer in instantaneous motion, its kinetic energy is $0$ but the potential energy of the system is maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If energy is conserved the answer is no, unless there is no change in potential energy.

Remember, $U + E_k = E$ , so $ E_k = E - U $ meaning that when $U$ is minimum, $E_k$ is maximum, so the only way that E_k will be minimal too, is if U is constant (and then implying it is both minimum and maximum)

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes. If you have friction on a hill, and a body is sliding from the top of the hill such that it stops due to friction at the bottom, both potential energy and kinetic energy are minimum at the bottom.

Comment: And what is the condition for maximum

Comment: I don't think it is really possible, as energy should be conserved. In the other case (the one given in the answer), mechanical energy gets converted to heat energy, and energy is conserved.